# Simple image rotator with jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="rotator">
<img src="../images/photos/DSC02625.jpg"/>
<img src="../images/photos/IMG_4825.jpg"/>
<img src="../images/photos/IMG_4869.jpg"/>
</div>
```

What will be the easiest way to create a simple image rotator using jQuery 1.3.2?

I don't want to use plugins...

A fade will be nice to have.

Thanks :)

Comment: Copy and paste the code of Cycle Lite plugin in your code =) http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/

Comment: I don't want to use plugins for each effect I want on a page. And I guess like there are others :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var $rotator = $(".rotator");
$rotator.find("img:gt(0)").hide();
setTimeout(Rotate, 1000);

function Rotate() {
    var $current = $rotator.find("img:visible");
    var $next = $current.next();
    if ($next.length == 0) $next = $rotator.find("img:eq(0)");
    $current.hide();
    $next.show();
    setTimeout(Rotate, 1000);
}
```

---

**example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/LMw6F/**

Comment: Thanks! Working like a charm! :)

Answer (score 2):

I made a few updates... Overlapping fadeOut and fadeIn with CSS for absolute positioning...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $rotator = $(".rotator");
    $rotator.find("img:gt(0)").hide();
    setTimeout(Rotate, 3000);

    function Rotate() {
        var $current = $rotator.find("img:visible");
        var $next = $current.next();
        if ($next.length == 0) $next = $rotator.find("img:eq(0)");
        $current.fadeOut(1000);
        $next.fadeIn(1000);
        setTimeout(Rotate, 3000);
    }

});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LMw6F/439/

Answer (score 0):

Great little piece of code. Two problems I had: one, I needed to link the images, and wrapping them in an href tag breaks the code. Fix was to wrap each image and link in a div tag and point the function at that. I also wanted to use fadeIn/Out for a softer transition:

```
$current.fadeOut(1000);
$next.fadeIn(1000);
```

This seemed to work fine until I looked at it in Explorer. 
I used absolute positioning to keep the images stacked on top of each other, but it turns out--facepalm--guess what? NO version of Explorer supports fading on an absolute-positioned element. Various attempts at doing without absolute positioning all involved having the images hop around disconcertingly as the new image faded in and the old one faded out. The fix that finally worked was using the callback function to trigger the fadeIn only when the fadeOut completed. Here's the fix I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $rotator = $(".rotator");
    $rotator.find("div:gt(0)").hide();
    setTimeout(Rotate, 6000);

    function Rotate() {
        var $current = $rotator.find("div:visible");
        var $next = $current.next();
        if ($next.length == 0) $next = $rotator.find("div:eq(0)");
        $current.fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $next.fadeIn(1000); 
        });
        setTimeout(Rotate, 6000);
    }

});
```